# htaccess duplicate file_put_contents

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

i created a log class. All works fine and the method "add" appends data to X.log. The problem is, when i turn on htaccess, file_put_contents wrote 2 lines (not one).

Basically, i tryed without class, only writing a file_put_contents in index + htaccess, and ever duplicate the log.

The problem looks like a htaccess routing twice.

This is the minimal code:

index.php:

```
DEFINE('BASE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));
DEFINE('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
DEFINE( 'LOG_PATH' , BASE_PATH . DS . "var" . DS . "log" . DS );
file_put_contents(LOG_PATH."1.log", "hola".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
die();
```

.htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(var|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for help!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser requests favicon.ico. And likely you don't have one - so request is being rewritten to `index.php` thus you have more than 1 record added.

Just look at your access.log and see the actual urls requested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zerkms, thats correct, the problem was favicon.
I added this condition to .htaccess, if anyone need it:

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon\.ico$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Thanks again zerkms.